# NTPD keep using UTC

Tags: switch, ntp, utc

What I'm trying to do with NTPD is syncronize all of our switches (3Com Baseline Switch 2928-PWR Plus) but instead of getting the localtime, they get UTC time.

The time in the server works well, the only issue is with the switches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTPD is ALWAYS in UTC. It don't know localtime. You need to synchronize your switches with NTP and configure them in your timezone. You should also think about summer time.
On Cisco, I do

```
service timestamps log datetime localtime show-timezone
clock timezone CEST 1
clock summer-time CEST recurring last Sun Mar 2:00 last Sun Oct 2:00
ntp server X.X.X.X
```

For France.

It should exists on 3Com switches

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this switch doesnt seems to have that option, can i pre-set the offset in npd? or instead of using UTC, use my local time?

Comment: answer to question in comment: No. You cannot change the offset in ntp.